# API Manager passing JWT to backend service

Tags: wso2

A backend service needs to know the user for the service call.  Reading through the API 1.6.0 documentation I have configured it to generate JWT and removed and republished my services as stated.   Running tests, I am not seeing the JWT being passed to the backed service in the response headers in Fiddler.  I am not using the ESB or Identity services from WSO2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT information should be passed in the header under the parameter `X-JWT-Assertion`. The Content is been encoded. Use TCPMon to intercept the request and see if the API Manager is actually passing the JWT. This would be a good starting point to debug.

Comment: I had been looking in the wrong place for the JWT.   Wrong place is that I did not look from the server perspective as I was looking from my test client's perspective.Thanks.

Comment: Could you please reply here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537524/passing-end-user-details-from-client-to-real-backend-endpoint-via-jwt-token-in-w ? Thanks, Neha

Comment: Hello Nadeesha - Could you please share code to get X-JWT-Assertion at WebService /controller?

Comment: Below blog gives instructions on how to extract the HTTP headers. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/