# Passing end-user details from client to real backend endpoint via JWT token in WSO2 APIM

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2-as

I am new to `WSO2 API Manager` using version `1.9.1`. I am trying to implement the `WSO2 APIM + JWT assertion` looking at http://lalajisureshika.blogspot.in/2013/06/passing-end-user-details-from-client-to.html and http://sumedha.blogspot.in/2012/08/using-jwt-to-send-application-user.html (but the steps are not too good enough to understand). I changed following from `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml`

```
<APIConsumerAuthentication>
    <SecurityContextHeader>X-JWT-Assertion</SecurityContextHeader>
    <ClaimsRetrieverImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever</ClaimsRetrieverImplClass>
    <ConsumerDialectURI>http://wso2.org/claims</ConsumerDialectURI>
    <SignatureAlgorithm>SHA256withRSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
    <EnableTokenGeneration>true</EnableTokenGeneration>
</APIConsumerAuthentication>
```

Please find attachment of few images, so it will give more idea about the failure:

[image]

I also subscribe my application and when try to execute command from **"API Console"**, I see very wired error.
[image]

Also TCP/IP Monitor tool shows 
[image]

[image]

**Please help me what is the issue is?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the error log which is printed in the *wso2carbon.log* (< APIM Home>/reposiory/logs) or terminal. it will be more useful to identify the reason to you error.

or else you can try other way To capture the outgoing message as mentioned below

Uncomment
*log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG*

in the log4j.properties file which can be found from {AM_Home}/repository/conf

restart server and invoke the subscribed api. you will get message like this in APIM with JWT-Assertion.

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2013-06-29 09:05:05,548] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-1>>X-JWT-Assertion: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJTSEEyNTZ3aXRoUlNBIiwieDV0IjoiTm1KbU9HVXhNelpsWWpNMlpEUmhOVFpsWVRBMVl6ZGhaVFJpT1dFME5XSTJNMkptT1RjMVpBPT0ifQ==.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.YtVaDtRYtfUkVDvwe9V8oqsXK8OkB4HUhsQS2z3ngWRNjAktSKWlH+Is9T5EQnsg8hrsJQ4nKDdwDWHAUIFxIsb7bX/Y1O+WSLMLZYQ11WVzFaw50BJuqPbL9ZOfux1iRnm4ZbxClVSan72g/w8a05UnCvsGyIh5oCP4RUsAhXo= {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
```

Comment: I was able to solve this. I was supposed to be using TCPMon in eclipse using TCPMon.jar file. It gives me result. We should not be using Eclipse provided TCPMon